# How to make a promise in Typescript to read 2 files and concatenate output and then print total result?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

I have a script in Typescript that works for reading files from S3 but now want to read 2 files, concatinate the output of both and then print as a `total_string`.

```
var total_string = '';
var files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt'];

for (var file of files) {
  var s3_params = {
    Bucket: 'bucket1', 
    Key: file
  }

  s3.getObject(s3_params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("\nError!!!\n");
      console.log(err, err.stack); 
    }
    else {
      console.log("Data in a file:", data); 
      let objectData = data.Body.toString('utf-8');
      console.log("objectData:\n", objectData);  
      total_string = total_string.concat(objectData);
    }
  });
}

console.log(total_string);
```

Currently - `total_string` is printing before other ones are executed so need to convert above code into Promise I believe..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Yes, promises sound like a good idea. Should become something like `Promise.all(filenames.map(readFile)).then(concat).then(writeOutputFile)`

Comment: How do you pass values (content of each file) from one function (readFile) to another (writeOutputFile)?